# How to fix an error during generating PDF: PdfBoxTextRenderer.getWidth(PdfBoxTextRenderer.java:300)

Tags: java, html-to-pdf, openhtmltopdf

I use [openhtmltopdf](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.openhtmltopdf) library to convert my html templates to PDF:

```
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {
        for (String html : htmlPagesWithValues) {
            PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
            builder.defaultTextDirection(BaseRendererBuilder.TextDirection.LTR);
            builder.useDefaultPageSize(210, 297, BaseRendererBuilder.PageSizeUnits.MM);
            builder.useProtocolsStreamImplementation(new InternalFSStreamFactory(), "localProtocol");
            builder.withHtmlContent(html, "");
            builder.useSVGDrawer(new BatikSVGDrawer());
            builder.usePDDocument(doc);
            PdfBoxRenderer renderer = builder.buildPdfRenderer();
            renderer.createPDFWithoutClosing();
        }
        doc.save(os);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.debug("Stacktrace: ", ex);
    }
```

During generating PDF file I am getting the following stacktrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.openhtmltopdf.pdfboxout.PdfBoxTextRenderer.getWidth(PdfBoxTextRenderer.java:300)
>       at com.openhtmltopdf.layout.Breaker.doBreakText(Breaker.java:147)
>       at com.openhtmltopdf.layout.Breaker.doBreakText(Breaker.java:115)
>       at com.openhtmltopdf.layout.Breaker.breakText(Breaker.java:109)
>       at com.openhtmltopdf.layout.InlineBoxing.layoutText(InlineBoxing.java:959)
>
> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I use images on PDF file that hosted on our server. The [Openpdftohtml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.openhtmltopdf) library tried to access the images by the our public URL but this URL was not available. After adding access PDF is successfully created. I've also opened the issue on Github: https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/issues/267

Comment: It seems your issue was closed because you didn't provide a test case. Even though the library could probably benefit from a better exception message.

Comment: I've fully described the problem and answered on my own question after the reason was found.

Comment: The problem is that line 300 in that class could only throw a NPE when a variable 'font' is null, so it's obviously not a good exception message if it was caused by some file not being accessible.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. It was taken some time before I found where was issue.